# Returning a List of Nodes that are Generic Types C#

Tags: c#, generics, tree

I am learning about generics and there's clearly something basic I am not understanding about them.

I have a Node class and a function that will populate a binary tree of nodes and return this tree as a list. I want the nodes to have a generic data type for their values so I made the Node class like this:

```
class Node<T>
    {
        public T dataval;
        public Node<T> left;
        public Node<T> right;
        public Node(T data)
        {
            this.dataval = data;
            this.left = null;
            this.right = null;
        }

    }
```

Now when creating the function, I am trying to make new Nodes with a primitive type such as an int or char. Here's what I have tried and the errors I am getting.

```
public static List<Node<T>> createTree<T>(int length) 
{   
                //    a
                //   / \ 
                //  b   c
                // / \   \
                //d   e   f
            Node<T> a = new Node<T>(1);     // cannot convert from 'int' to 'T'
            Node<T> b = new Node<int>(2);   // cannot implicitly convert 'Node<int>' to 'Node<T>'
            Node<int> c = new Node<int>(3);  // No error here, but error in return statement     
            var d = new Node<int>(4);     // No errror here, but error in return statement
            var e = new Node<int>(5);
            var f = new Node<int>(6);
            a.left = b;
            a.right = c;
            b.left = d;
            b.right = e;
            c.right = f;

            return new List<Node<int>> { a, b, c, d, e, f};  // cannot convert from 'Node<int>' to 'Node<T>'
             
}
```

I think my misunderstanding of generics begins with creating these new objects and instantiating them with a primitive data type. Not sure what's going wrong with this process.

Comment: Side note: public properties, fields, and methods are Pascal-case in C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your generic `createTree<T>` method promises to create a tree whatever the type `T` might be. So clearly you cannot assume that `T` is `int`.

**Option 1**: make the method specifically create a tree of `int`s:

Change the signature to `List<Node<int>> createTree(int length)` and use `Node<int>` in the body whereever you now have `Node<T>`.

**Option 2**: pass the values from outside

If you want to keep the method generic, you need to provide the values of correct type from the caller.

This could be done in the form of additional parameters of type `T` like `List<Node<T>> createTree<T>(T aval, T bval, T cval, T eval, T fval)` or `List<Node<T>> createTree<T>(T[] values)` or in the form of a factory method `List<Node<T>> createTree<T>(Func<T> valueFactory)`

Comment: So I guess what I'm confused on is my case in the 'a' variable I am trying to instantiate. What I want is to create a node that can accept any type, so I thought using Node<T> = new Node<T>(val) would solve this, but it doesn't like any value I put into 'val'.

Comment: Also, I understand that I could make everything <int> instead of <T>, which is what I was doing at first, but I what if I wanted the function to make Nodes of type char and return the list of nodes of type char. I wanted to see if I could do this using generics. Thanks for the speedy response.

Comment: You definition of `Node<T>` is fine. The problem is that when you create a concrete tree you need to be specific about what `T` is. I extended my answer trying to make your options clearer.

Comment: Ok so what I did was create an array of nodes of type T before I called the function and passed this array as a parameter into the createTree function like you stated in option 2.

Comment: What was confusing me was that I was wanting the type to get automatically converted from type T to type int when I made a new node within the createTree function which is obviously not allowed. I think I understand a bit better now. Thanks.